Is there any difference between commerce and merchants tags?
Current state:

commerce has 14 questions
described as “The transacting of business using Bitcoin or related technologies”
merchants has 6 questions
(without a description).

I was considering a merge, but I'm asking first whether there is any difference?
If there is one, how could the descriptions be updated?

Hmm, I think that the commerce tag is a bit more general than merchants. For example, talking about commerce could include payment processors, identity verification for business, TOR technology as used for shops and so forth. Merchants on the other hand could involve questions about the people that are doing the trading, such as business and shop owners.
I guess the distinction might be a bit arbitrary at times and the tags could overlap often. I still think they should be separated, but I wouldn't mind a merge should it happen.

Did I see the word “discussion”? Besides, “payment-processors”, “identity-verification”, and “tor” should be tags on their own. The meanings of the two tags now seem so vague that I wonder whether they should not be removed altogether.

As we by now have shopping-car-interface, exchanges, finance, companies, merchant-services, ecommerce, payments, payment-processors, merchants, and a number of tags for specific services, it seems that there should be an appropriate tag available for any area of commerce.
I'd actually say that we could consolidate a few more of them.
